# can i have a multi-height bootstrap grid layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout I am trying to achieve.

Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3

Col 2 is "col-md-6 col-lg-6" and Col 1 and Col 3 are "col-md-3 col-lg-3" respectively

I want something like this:

[image: desired Layout]

However I end up with everything on one side like this:

[image: not wanted]

And if I try and use pull or push classes I end up with unwanted spaces:

[image]

Here is some sample code that is close to what I have:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    content1
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    content2
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    content3
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    content4
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    content5
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way to get the first image like result

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="bg-danger">1</div>
          <br />
          <div class="bg-danger">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="bg-danger">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="bg-danger">4</div>
          <br />
          <div class="bg-danger">5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Or another way to put columns inside a column

```html
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="bg-danger">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="bg-danger">1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="bg-danger">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="bg-danger">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="bg-danger">1</div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and to control `height` you can use
That will make all elements with the same height.
and don't put it if you want the height to be as the content of each column.

```css
.row {
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
}
```

Comment: Ended up nesting them and achieving what I was going for. Thanks for the input!